# mvc Ajax won't launch after first refresh call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

ajax Code:

```
        $('.remove-item').click(function () {
                var iddata = $(this).attr("data");
                var confirmation = confirm("are you sure?");
                if (confirmation == true) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "@Url.Action("_Delete","Item")",
                        data: { Id: iddata },
                        ajaxasync: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                            $('.wrap').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Basically after first succesfull attempt to call this ajax, I'm refreshing/replacing partial view with `(data)` and when I try to delete item from list that is in data.. nothing is happening
I don't know what info is neede yet for this.

Comment: If the data your updating contains elements with `class="remove-item"`, and your want to handle the `.click()` event of those elements, then you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - `$(.wrap').on('click', .remove-item', function() { ....`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah, I tried it. IT ended up not launching at all even withing first try ;l

Comment: Then you have done something else wrong :)

Comment: also need to make sure that the `wrap` class example given is some element that actually exists in your html... can't use `$('.wrap')` if it doesn't match anything you have